# Unbind at System.exit(0)

Tags: rmi, unbind, system.exit

I'm working with Java RMI. The problem is that, by closing a thread, or call `System.exit(0)`, I need the object registered with the RMI registry to execute an `unbind()` to remove all associations with the object. When we perform `System.exit(0)`, the object is already registered with the RMI registry.

How I can do so by calling `System.exit(0)` the `unbind()` is made of the object in particular? I had thought about making a `System.exit()` override , but apparently that's not the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that, by closing a thread, or call `System.exit(0)`, I need the object registered with the RMI registry to execute an `unbind()` to remove all associations with the object.

So do that. But there is no such thing as 'closing a thread', and even *exiting* a thread doesn't require you to unbind anything.

> When we perform `System.exit(0)`, the object is already registered with the RMI registry.

Good, so the `unbind()` will succeed. Not sure what point is being made her. Did you mean '*still* registered'?

> How I can do so by calling `System.exit(0)` the `unbind()` is made of the object in particular?

You can't. You have to precede the `System.exit()` call with an `unbind()` call.

> I had thought about making a `System.exit()` override , but apparently that's not the solution.

You can't override static methods, and `System` is final.

It seems you may have `System.exit()` spattered all over the place, which is already poor practice.

The simple answer is not to call `System.exit()` at all, but to unbind and unexport the object *instead*. Then the RMI threads will exit and your JVM will exit of its own accord, as long as you don't have any non-daemon threads of your own.